# Finding which subclass to call

Tags: java

I am currently studying more on OOP concepts. The program I am writing is for drawing shapes on the screen by mouse clicking then dragging to the desired location and releasing the mouse. Well the user can select which shape to draw by a combo box selection. This combo box is made of items of type Shape. Shape is an abstract class for multiple shape objects. The shape class has two methods, draw(graphics) and getColor(). When the mouse is released I need to know which shape object is being used to draw the correct shape. I can use instanceof to check for which shape it might be but I feel like this is sort of a bad practice or a design smell. I also thought about creating two non abstract methods in the shape class to set the points from mouse released and mouse clicked. All classes related to a shape are not of the java API just for learning purposes. What approach would you take and why?

```
public class ShapeMakerPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JPanel controls;

    private JPanel currentColor;

    private JComboBox<Shape> shapeChoice;

    private JCheckBox filled;

    private JButton undo;

    private JButton clear;

    private List<Shape> list = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public ShapeMakerPanel() {
      controls = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 10));
      currentColor = new JPanel();
      shapeChoice = new JComboBox<Shape>();
      undo = new JButton("Undo");
      clear = new JButton("Clear");
      filled = new JCheckBox("Filled");

      //Anything below this line in the constructor is being moved to a
      //createUI method, so please ignore this.
      controls.setName("controls");
      currentColor.setName("currentColor");
      undo.setName("undo");
      clear.setName("clear");
      shapeChoice.setName("shapeChoice");

      currentColor.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      currentColor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));

      shapeChoice.addItem(new Rectangle());
      shapeChoice.addItem(new Oval());

      controls.add(shapeChoice);
      controls.add(currentColor);
      controls.add(filled);
      controls.add(undo);
      controls.add(clear);

      controls.addMouseListener(new ControlsPanelMouseListener());

      add(controls);
    }

    public List<Shape> getShapes () {
      return list;
    }


private class ControlsPanelMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    private Point mousePressed;

    private Point mouseReleased;

    private ControlsPanelMouseListener () {
        mousePressed = new Point();
        mouseReleased = new Point();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        mousePressed = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
           Shape shape = (Shape) shapeChoice.getSelectedItem();
           mouseReleased = e.getPoint();

           //Get points to correct shape.....

           //Call the shape draw method....
           shape.draw(getGraphics());
        }        
    }
```

Shape abstract class

```
public abstract class Shape
{
   public abstract void draw(Graphics context);

   public abstract Color getColor();
}
```

Shape Hierarchy
[Shape Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRoAn.png)

Comment: why was this down voted?

Comment: Why do you need to know which shape it is? The point of good abstraction is that you don't need to know that. Regarding downvote: wall-of-text formatting and no example I guess.

Comment: I don't really need to know which shape it is but in an instance of that I would need some way to get the points to the draw method of the shape subclass. Which would put me at creating additional methods in the shape class to set the points.

Comment: Confused: an instance knows which type it is, can you illustrate what you mean with a bit of code? And sometimes you need to add more methods to the shape class so you can interact with all subclasses in an abstract uniform way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of OOP and inheritance is that you can have a base class (or interface) which defines the methods that ALL the sub-classes have BUT the sub-classes will actually perform the logic

Consider

```
public class Triangle extends Shape {
   ...
   public void draw () {
     System.out.println ("I have three sides");
   }
}

public class Square extends Shape {
   ...
   public void draw () {
     System.out.println ("I have four sides");
   }
}

... main () {

    Shape shapeA = new Triangle ();
    Shape shapeB = new Square ();

    shapeA.draw ();
    shapeB.draw ();
```

// output

```
     I have three sides
     I have four sides
```

Comment: So really I need to maintain abstraction by creating methods in the super class which would be relevant to all subclasses.....

Comment: Yes, if there isn't any common code, but only only common structure then consider using an interface

Comment: would you do public void setCoordinateAxes(Point startingPoint, Point endingPoint) { //some code} or would you do public void setStartingPoint(Point p) {} and setEndingPoint(Point p) {}

Comment: My apologies for the code in the comment it is hard to read. This would be applied to the shape class.

Comment: Hard to tell Charles based upon this code.  if you are likely to need and individual setter and getter for each point then the separate methods would be re-using existing code, but otherwise, up to you.